# sql query group

Tags: sql, group-by

SQL query question

I have a query like

```
select proposal_id, service_id,account_type 
from table1
```

The result is like this:

```
proposal_id  service_id  account_type
   1          1001        INTERVAL
   1          1002        INTERVAL
   2          1003        NON INTERVAL
   2          1004        NON INTERVAL
   3          1005        NON INTERVAL
   3          1006        INTERVAL
```

I want to write a query: for each proposal_id, if all the service have INTERVAL then get 'INTERVAL', if all NON-INTERVAL get 'NON-INTERVAL', if both, get 'Both'

For the example above, it should return

```
proposal_id   account_type
   1           INTERVAL
   2           NON-INTERVAL
   3           BOTH
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Then you don't need all those `<br />` tags and all the dashes instead of spaces, either.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data:

```
declare @table table (id int, sid int, acc nvarchar(20))
insert @table VALUES (1,1001,'INTERVAL'),(1,1002,'INTERVAL'),(2,1003,'NON INTERVAL'),(2,1004,'NON INTERVAL'),
(3,1005,'NON INTERVAL'),(3,1006,'INTERVAL')
```

Query:

```
select x.Id
    ,   CASE counter
            WHEN 1 THEN x.Account_Type
            ELSE 'BOTH'
        END AS Account_Type
from (
    select  Id, Count(DISTINCT(acc)) AS counter, MAX(acc) As Account_Type
    from @table
    GROUP BY Id
) x
```

Results

```
Id          Account_Type
----------- --------------------
1           INTERVAL
2           NON INTERVAL
3           BOTH
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
      b.proposal_id
     ,CASE
        WHEN s1.proposal_id IS NOT NULL AND s2.proposal_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'BOTH'
        WHEN s1.proposal_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'INTERVAL'
        WHEN s2.proposal_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'NON-INTERVAL'
        ELSE 'UNKNOWN'
     END [account_type] 
FROM table1 b
  LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT proposal_id,account_type FROM table1 WHERE account_type = 'INTERVAL'
    ) s1
      ON b.proposal_id = s1.proposal_id
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT proposal_id,account_type FROM table1 WHERE account_type = 'NON-INTERVAL'
    )s2
      ON b.proposal_id = s2.proposal_id
```

Comment: This can surely do. But I prefer a solution without self-join. Thank you all the same.

Comment: The other solution is better.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `count distinct` to determinate if it is both then use `CASE` to determinate what to display

```
SELECT DISTINCT proposal.proposal_id, 
       CASE cou 
            WHEN 1 THEN type ELSE 'Both' END as TYPE
FROM proposal
INNER JOIN (SELECT proposal_id, count(distinct type) cou 
            FROM proposal GROUP BY proposal_id) inn 
       ON proposal.id = inn.id
```

Comment: Thank you, the answer is similar with @Paddy 's.

Answer (score 0):

```
select proposal_id,
case when count(distinct account_type) > 1 then 'BOTH'
    else max(account_type)
    end
from table1
group by proposal_id
```

You have the [fiddler here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3058/21).

Comment: Thank you. But@Paddy is first.